# Unicode characters are saved in a funny way in the DB

Tags: urls, wp-insert-post, characters

I have a custom website in which I am using `wp_insert_post()` to manually create posts that have a title which has characters thare are non-English Unicode letters (Arabic to be more specific).

The URL that gets created by `wp_insert_post()` is something similar to the following:

http://example.dev/%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b3%d9%8a%d8%a7-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b9%d9%85%d9%84-%d8%b9%d9%84%d9%89-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%83%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a7%d8%ad-%d9%81%d8%b9%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%b6%d8%af-%d9%85%d8%b1/

(note that I have permalinks enabled)

Now, how do I prevent the above link from being saved as show? How do I ensure the Unicode characters are used instead of the %-and-number combination for each letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not touch that string. URLs [must be percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), and what you see is the slug for the URL. A browser will display the characters just fine, so don’t worry about the database.